# Find a norm of operator form l1 to l1

Tags: functional-analysis

I have an operator $A: \ell_1 \to \ell_1, Ax = (x_1+x_2, x_1-x_2, x_3,...,x_k,...)$

AFAIK, norm of $\ell_1$ is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|$

How to find a norm of this operator?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal why? How to prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

\begin{align*}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\| #1 \right\|_1}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left| #1 \right|}
\left\| A \right\|
&=
\sup_{x \in \ell^1}
\frac{\norm{Ax}}{\norm{x}} \\
&= \sup_{x \in \ell^1}
\frac{\abs{x_1 + x_2} + \abs{x_1 - x_2} + \displaystyle \sum_{i=3}^ \infty |x_i|}
{\abs{x_1} + \abs{x_2} + \displaystyle \sum_{i=3}^\infty |x_i|} \\
&=
\sup_{x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}}
\frac{\abs{x + y} + \abs{x - y} + \abs{z}}
{\abs{x} + \abs{y} + \abs{z}}
\end{align*}

**Further Hint**

Triangle inequality: $|x + y| + |x - y| \le 2|x| + 2|y|$

Now try $x, y, z = 1, 0, 0$.

Comment: But is there supremum of this function? I think no, WolframAlpha says no either, but how to prove it?

Comment: @user23791 I added a further hint.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your further hint. So this function will be equal to 2 in $(1,0,0)$. And what does it mean?

Comment: @user23791 The supremum exists and is achieved.  To show this, you need to prove (1) the expression is bounded above by the maximum (see "Triangle inequality" of my further hint) and (2) the maximum is attained.

Comment: So, supremum is 2, right?

Comment: @user23791 yep.